# How to change this code to kotlin to view a pdf from firebase database

Tags: kotlin, pdf

How can i change my java code to kotlin code to view a pdf from firebase database

public class javaclasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView text1;
private PDFView pdfView;
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mref = database.getReference("url");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);

    pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView33);
    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text11);

    mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            text1.setText(value);
            Toast.makeText(javaclasActivity.this, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String url = text1.getText().toString();
            new RetrivePdfStream().execute(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(javaclasActivity.this, "failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });}
```

// i am facing a problen on this below code

```
    class RetrivePdfStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
        }


    }
}
```

to this kotlin file

class pdfActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var pdfview: PDFView
lateinit var text1 : TextView
var database:FirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
var mref :DatabaseReference=database.getReference("url")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf)

    pdfview=findViewById(R.id.pdfView33)
    text1=findViewById(R.id.text11)

    



}
```

}

the main problem is this

class RetrivePdfStream  <String, Void, InputStream> {

Answer (score 0):

You might want to fix some of the formatting here.

Also, if I understood correctly, you want to migrate Java to Kotlin.
For the `RetrivePdfStream` in Kotlin, you aren't inheriting from `AsyncTask`.
Do this like so:

```
class RetrivePdfStream : AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>() { ... }
```